# Как совместить текстовые команды и слэш команды в боте дискорд

Tags: python, discord.py

Добавил в бота дискорд слэш команды, но перестали работать текстовые. Не понимаю с чем это связанно и как решить эту проблему.

```py
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned, sync_commands_debug=True, test_guilds= [968372517326708786])

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.slash_command(description="Команды")
async def cmds(inter):
    await inter.response.send_message("Команды:\nКу\nПривет\nДаров\nХай\nСалам\nШалом\nhelp\ninfo")
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:  
        return
    prefix = "&"
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + 'Привет'):         #Привет
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + 'привет'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
#    if message.content.startswith(prefix + 'Прив'):           #Прив
#        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
#    if message.content.startswith(prefix + 'прив'):
#        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
#    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "Всем привет"):    #Всем привет
#        await message.channel.send('Привет!')
#    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "всем привет"):
#        await message.channel.send('Привет!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "Ку"):             #Ку
        await message.channel.send('Даров!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "ку"):
        await message.channel.send('Даров!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "Хай"):            #Хай
        await message.channel.send('Приветик!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "хай"):
        await message.channel.send('Приветик!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "Даров"):          #Даров
        await message.channel.send('Хай!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "даров"):
        await message.channel.send('Хай!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "Салам"):          #Салам
        await message.channel.send('Салют!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "салам"):
        await message.channel.send('Салют!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "Шалом"):           #Шалом
        await message.channel.send('Здрасьте!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "шалом"):
        await message.channel.send('Здрасьте!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "help"):
        emb = discord.Embed(title="Нужна помощь? Я откликаюсь на:", description="\n&Привет\n&Всем привет\n&Ку\n&Хай\n&Даров\n&Салам\n&Прив\n&Шалом")
        await message.channel.send(embed=emb)
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "info"):
        emb = discord.Embed(title="Обо мне", description="\nПросто бот. Создан **@Bad Boy#4708** 05.05.2022. В даный момент нахдится на бета тесте на сервере AlexGyver community\n\nВерсия 1.0 beta")
        await message.channel.send(embed=emb)
            

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: @Corrygan верно подметил, что не стоит делать проверки в `on_message`. Вот почему: https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/problems/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20on_message.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы создавать команды не нужно делать проверки с `startswith` в `on_message`

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=!, intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Сделали префикс `!`(для примера). А дальше создаёте асинхронные функции, например:

```
@client.command(aliases=['удалить'])
async def delete(ctx, amount: int=None)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.send(f'Удалено {amount} сообщений!')
```

Тогда не будет проблем с слеш и текстовыми командами.